# IF ELSE Not working in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been stuck on this for about 30 minutes and I dont know if im overlooking anything, but i keep getting the following error (mostly meaning my SQL is invalid):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object...

SQL:

```
IF (SELECT value FROM votes WHERE thread = ? AND owner = ?) THEN 
    UPDATE votes SET (value = ?) WHERE thread = ? AND owner = ? 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO votes (thread, owner, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
END IF
```

PHP:

```
$stmt = $this->database->prepare("IF (SELECT value FROM votes WHERE thread = ? AND owner = ?) THEN UPDATE votes SET (value = ?) WHERE thread = ? AND owner = ? ELSE INSERT INTO votes (thread, owner, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?) END IF");
$stmt->bind_param("dddddddd", $this->id, $userId, $value, $this->id, $userId, $this->id, $userId, $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

According to the MySQL documentation, I should be correct?

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: @ErolKESKİN MySQLI

Comment: @CodeCaster Nope. The other thread is talking about how to get the error. This is about why the error is happening and how to get around it

Comment: @Machavity yeah, so actually this should be closed as off-topic: missing [mcve]. The duplicate helps the OP get the actual error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IF` statement only works in programming blocks -- stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

You can do what you want with `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO votes (thread, owner, value)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

For this to work, you should define a unique key/constraint on `thread`/`owner`:

```
create unique index unq_votes_thread_owner on votes(thread, owner);
```

Comment: `IF` works in `SELECT` and  `UPDATE`. But your method is the prefered one. Even better than `REPLACE`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany . . . Don't confuse the `IF()` *function* with the `IF` statement.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this.

The [`if` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) you refer to is for stored procedures/function (and not for queries).

You can use two different queries for that:

1. select (**sql**)
2. check the result (**php**).
3. insert/update (**sql**) based on the result (checked with php)

Comment: I was hoping I could do this in one query (the fewer the better :) )

Comment: @HunterMitchell, depending on the situation you can use the `replace into` syntax, but it really depends on your data.

Comment: Ill look into that. Havent had the need for anything other than simple INSERTs etc. :D